# Need help showing the supremum of a function exists.

Tags: limits, functions, inequality

I was wondering if anyone knows a technique for proving that this function has a supremum less than infinity for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ ,$x \in [-1,1]$ (I am very certain that it does).

The function is, for a fixed $y \in (1,\infty)$, $$f(x)=\frac{||x+1|^y-|x|^y-1|}{|x|^{y-1}+|x|}.$$

I've tried lots of methods, like taking the derivative (a huge mess), and stringing together a chain of $\leq$'s, which doesn't seem to work. Is there an easy way to show this?

Thanks! I did not know what tag to put this under, so feel free to tag it appropriately if you know a better one.

Comment: $x$ in which set?

Comment: Im not sure, but maybe the tag inequality or such might be good. Again, not sure though.

Comment: What does "over $[1,1]$" mean? Maybe "over $[-1,1]$" was intended?

Comment: Sorry, x is a real number between -1 and 1.

Comment: What happens at $x=0$?  If the limit $L$ exists, and we define $f(0)=L$, then the function is continuous on a compact set, so it must be bounded.

Comment: First do some special cases.  Say $y=2$ or $y=10$.  Then see what is involved in those cases.

Comment: Everything is ok at $0$. Here is an example of how it looks: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%7C%28%7C%28x%2B1%29%7C%29%5E25-%28%7Cx%7C%29%5E25-1%7C%29%5C%28%28%7Cx%7C%29%5E%2824%29%2B%28%7Cx%7C%29%29

Answer (score 1):

First, you can show that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\begin{cases}y&y>2\\1&y=2\\0&1<y<2\end{cases}$$

So in all cases, the limit exists and is finite.  Hence, if we define $$f(0):=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$$

Then $f$ is a continuous function on the compact set $[-1,1]$, and is thus bounded.  In other words, it has a finite supremum.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Any tips on showing that limit is $y$ for the $y>2$ case?

Comment: You can try using L'Hospital, splitting into the left and right hand limits to get rid of the absolute values to simplify derivatives.

Comment: That worked! Thanks.